# Why $\ker N_{E/F}$ is a map from $E^{\times}$ to $F^{\times}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

I am reading the [lecture notes](http://www.ma.huji.ac.il/~deshalit/new_site/files/unitary.pdf). In the end of page 1, it is said that $\ker N_{E/F}$ is a map from $E^{\times}$ to $F^{\times}$. Here $E/F$ is a quadratic field extension.

Let $\alpha \in E$ and define a map $\alpha: E \to E$ given by $x \mapsto \alpha x$. By definition, $N_{E/F}(\alpha)$ is the determinant of the map $\alpha$. Therefore $N_{E/F}$ is a map from $E$ to $F$. But why $\ker N_{E/F}$ is a map from $E^{\times}$ to $F^{\times}$? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me put in some parentheses for you:

$$E^1:=\ker\color{Red}{\big(}N_{E/F}:E^\times\to F^\times\color{Red}{\big)}.$$